# Retain Umlaut Character when using Split in Ruby

Tags: ruby, split

Why does this code (that contains an umlaut):

```
text = "Some super text with a german umlaut Wirtschaftsprüfer"
words = text.split(/\W+/)
words.each do |w|
  puts w
end
```

Return this result (that does not retain the previously-given umlaut):

```
=> Some
=> super
=> text
=> with
=> a
=> german
=> umlaut
=> Wirtschaftspr
=> fer
```

Is there a way I can retain an umlaut when splitting a string in Ruby 1.9+?

EDIT: I use ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

Comment: Version of Ruby is important here. What are you using?

Comment: I use ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[\W]` just matches non word characters, i.e., it's equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, and so does not include (exclude?) special characters and diacritics. You can use

```
words = text.split(/[^[:word:]]/)
```

which matches all Unicode "word" characters, or

```
words = text.split(/[^\p{Latin}]/)
```

which matches characters in the Unicode Latin script.
Note that both of these will match special characters from other languages, not just German.

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html and look for (1) "Character Classes" and (2) "Character Properties."

Answer (score 2):

You could replace `/\W+/` by `/\s+/`  (`\s` matches space characters: space, tabs, new lines)

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this code [...] not retain the previously-given umlaut

Because `\W` matches a non-word *ASCII* character (i.e. not `a-z`, not `A-Z`, not `0-9` and not `_`) and `ü` is such a character.

> Is there a way I can retain an umlaut when splitting a string in Ruby 1.9+?

Sure, you can for example split by whitespace, which is the default if no pattern is given:

```
"Müllmann Straßenverkehr Wirtschaftsprüfer".split
=> ["Müllmann", "Straßenverkehr", "Wirtschaftsprüfer"]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html):

> /\W/ - A non-word character ([^a-zA-Z0-9_])

`ü` isn't a word character, so `\W` matches and splits there. `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}` are ruby shorthands to unicode uper and lowercase characters so you could do:

```
text.split /[^\p{Ll}\p{Lu}]/
```

... and should split even the most exotic strings.

Answer (score 0):

because you used /\W/ to split text which means anything not in this list:
a-zA-Z0-9

try split

[^\w\ü]

which is

^ not in
\w a-zA-Z0-9
\ü

(alternatively look at creating your own pattern which you can reuse)

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html ref